# Issues with user function/ map to read in and combine DBF files in R

Tags: r, dictionary, dplyr

I have written a function to read in a set of dbf files. Unfortunately, these files are very large, and I wouldn't want anyone to have to run them on my behalf.

```
 readfun_dbf = function(path) {
  test = read.dbf(path, as.is = TRUE) # dont convert to factors 
  test
}
```

dbfiles identifies the list of file names. map_dfr applies my function to the list of files and row binds them together. I've used very similar code to read in some text files, so I know the logic works.

```
dbfiles = list.files(pattern = "assign.dbf", full.names = F, recursive = T)
dbf_combined <- map_dfr(dbfiles, readfun_dbf)
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
Error: Column `ASN_PCT` can't be converted from integer to character
```

So I ran the read.dbf command on all the files individually and noticed that some dfb files were being read in with all their feilds as characters, and some were being read in with some as integers and characters. I figured that map_dfr needs the fields to be of the same type to bind them, so I added the mutate_all command to my function--but it's still throwing the same error.

```
readfun_dbf = function(path) {
  test = read.dbf(path, as.is = TRUE) # dont convert to factors 
  **mutate_all(test,as.character)**
  test
}
```

Do you think the mixed field types are the issues? Or could it be something else? Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the value back to the object.

```
readfun_dbf = function(path) {
   test = read.dbf(path, as.is = TRUE) 
   test <- dplyr::mutate_all(test,as.character)
   return(test)
}
```

and then try :

```
dbf_combined <- purrr::map_dfr(dbfiles, readfun_dbf)
```